# Pass data from React to Sails and return value

Tags: reactjs, sails.js

In my React app I have three fields:

`firstNumber` = accept any number >0

`secondNumber` = accept any number >0

`operator` = accept +,-,*,% as a string

I want to send it as a POST request to Sails so it can make the calculation. For example: 2+3 returns 5. Then I would show the return value in React.

I have written the **React** part and I believe it is right.

```
  handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const inputField = {
      firstNumber: this.state.firstNumber,
      operator: this.state.operator, 
      secondNumber: this.state.secondNumber}
    const request = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ inputField })
    };
    fetch('http://localhost:1337/teste', request)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ total: data.valor}));
  }
```

In Sails I have created a controller to handle this. But I can't find a way to import the `inputField` and use the data of fistNumber, secondNumber, and operator in a function.

What are the necessary steps to do in Sails.js?

Answer (score 0):

In Sails, you might use Action2 controllers in your api/controllers folder.

```
module.exports = {

  friendlyName: 'Welcome user',

  description: 'Look up the specified user and welcome them, or redirect to a signup page if no user was found.',

  inputs: {
    userId: {
      description: 'The ID of the user to look up.',
      // By declaring a numeric example, Sails will automatically respond with `res.badRequest`
      // if the `userId` parameter is not a number.
      type: 'number',
      // By making the `userId` parameter required, Sails will automatically respond with
      // `res.badRequest` if it's left out.
      required: true
    }
  },

  exits: {
    success: {
      responseType: 'view',
      viewTemplatePath: 'pages/welcome'
    },
    notFound: {
      description: 'No user with the specified ID was found in the database.',
      responseType: 'notFound'
    }
  },

  fn: async function ({userId}) {

    // Look up the user whose ID was specified in the request.
    // Note that we don't have to validate that `userId` is a number;
    // the machine runner does this for us and returns `badRequest`
    // if validation fails.
    var user = await User.findOne({ id: userId });

    // If no user was found, respond "notFound" (like calling `res.notFound()`)
    if (!user) { throw 'notFound'; }

    // Display a personalized welcome view.
    return {
      name: user.name
    };
  }
};
```

So, you define your inputs and process them in `fn: function(inputs)` where you have access to `inputs.firstNumber` and the rest of fields.

Source:  https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers